# Save the output of a task: the error messages are not saved

Tags: symfony1

i have a long error message when i execute a task. In order to save
the output i'm writing

> task > foo.txt

But when i open foo.txt the error messages are not there.

Any idea? Any alternative?

symfony 1.4/propel

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 4):

Your only redirecting the stdout stream, and you need to trap the stderr stream as well.  The syntax varies depending on the shell you're using.  For example, in bash

`task &> foo.txt`

would redirect both stderr and stdout to foo.txt.